# how can I clean this data type object and transform it to type float maintaining Null and NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe column:

```
                           Hight
0                       
1               1,82 m (6 ft 0 in)
2        1,74 m (5 ft 9 in) metres
3               1,88 m (6 ft 2 in)
4                              NaN
5       1,80 m (5 ft 11 in) metres
```

How can I transform the column Hight to data type float and keep the NaN values?

Desired output:

```
Hight
0                              NaN
1                             1.82 
2                             1.74
3                             1.88
4                              NaN
5                             1.80
```

thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
pd.to_numeric(df.Hight.str.extract('([\d,]+) m')[0].str.replace(',','.'))
```

Output:

```
0     NaN
1    1.82
2    1.74
3    1.88
4     NaN
5    1.80
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Method 1:

Using [`positive lookahead`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) with regular expressions. We extract all the values before `<whitespace>m<whitespace>` with [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

```
pd.to_numeric(df['Hight'].str.extract('(^.*)(?=\sm\s)').replace(',', '.', regex=True)[0])

0   NaN  
1    1.82
2    1.74
3    1.88
4   NaN  
5    1.80
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

---

#### Method 2:

Using `Series.str.split`:

```
df['Hight'].str.split('(^.*)(?=\sm\s)').str[1].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a memoized method like this – it's blazing fast and pretty versatile:

```
def lookup_numeric(s):
    """
    This is an extremely fast approach to parsing numbers to floats.
    """
    lookup_vals = {}

    for x in s.unique():
        if type(x)==str and re.match('[0-9]+', x):
            x_new = x.replace(',','.')
            v = re.findall('[0-9\.]+', x_new)[0]
        else:
            v = np.nan

        # Now set the value
        lookup_vals[x] = v

    return s.map(lookup_vals)

# Output:
# lookup_numeric(df.Hight)
0     NaN
1    1.82
2    1.74
3    1.88
4     NaN
5    1.80
```